# ArcGIS Server Could Not Find 'System/GPServer/PublishingToolsEx'

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.5

I encounter this error which trying to register a PostgreSQL database:

> Unable to process request. Error handling service request :Could not find a service with the name 'System/GPServer/PublishingToolsEx' in the configured clusters. Service may be stopped or ArcGIS Server may not be running.

I am using ArcGIS Server 10.5 with patches installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PublishingToolsEx is only visible under the administrative API http://localhost:6080/arcgis/admin/services/System. Try to start it there. If you are unable to, federate ArcGIS Server with Portal for ArcGIS. That should force the service to start.

Edit: Typo <strike>federated</strike>